# How does PHP handle thousands/millions of requests ?

Tags: php, web-services

I've been porting some code from java to php, and noticed that php doesn't have multithreading. I'm just curious as to how else would web services handle thousands/millions of requests ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP doesn't care how many requests there are, it's the web server that has to handle/thread the request (instances).

Comment: Correct, as long as the web server is multi-threaded, it can launch each request into a separate thread.  Unless your web request is doing something very complex, there is nothing to gain by that single request being multi-threaded.  Also keep in mind, that by default, ASP.NET and JSP are only 1 thread, you have to specifically code things to use multiple threads, every step of the way.  They don't automatically give you some magic free multithreaded speed bonus just because it's supported.